# how to keep consumer alive even if producer exits

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

Say we have a simple pipeline:

```
a | b
```

say, `a` exits - is there a surefire way to keep `b` alive for an arbitrary amount of time (to complete a task etc).

Comment: "If the pipeline is not executed asynchronously (see [Lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists)), the shell waits for all commands in the pipeline to complete."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b` would not be terminated by `a` terminating.

```
$ { echo hello; } | { read message; printf 'got "%s"\n' "$message"; sleep 5; echo "ok, I'm done"; }
got "hello"
ok, I'm done
```

Here, `a` (the `echo hello`) would simply output a string and terminate.  The right hand side of the pipe (`b`) would read the string, output it, sleep for a while, and then do its final `echo` before terminating.

If `b` was terminated when `a` was, it would never have time to do what it needed to do.  The only thing `b` *can't* do here is to read more data from its standard input (an extra `read` at the end would get end-of-file immediately).

---

In the *other* scenario (not mentioned in the question), where `b` terminates before `a`, `a` would receive a `PIPE` signal if it tried to write to its standard output (across to the non-existing `b` process) and terminate from that (by default).

If it didn't try to write to the pipe, `a` would continue running until done.

Comment: ah nice, I always wondered when SIGPIPE was raised, so SIGPIPE is received by `a` if `b` exits before `a`?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes, correct, but _only if `a` tries to write to standard output_.

Comment: or stderr I assume (if stderr is connect to the consumer)

Comment: @AlexanderMills Ok, only if `a` tries to write to the pipe, no matter what the stream is that is connected to it.